# The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, pytz

I need to filter the lines where the date is today and not more than 2 hours ago according to local time (the code needs to be malleable as I travel to different timezones):

```python
from tzlocal import get_localzone
import pandas as pd
import pytz

df['DATA_HORA'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(f'{x["DATA"]} {x["HORA"]}', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'), axis=1)
local_tz = get_localzone()
local_tz = pytz.timezone(local_tz.zone)
df_today = df[(df['DATA_HORA'].dt.tz_localize(local_tz) >= (datetime.now(local_tz) - timedelta(hours=2))) & (df['DATA_HORA'].dt.date == datetime.now(local_tz).date())]
```

I tried to understand how to do it, according to the specific documentation about it:

https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html#getting-a-time-zone-s-name

But I was not successful, how should I proceed to find my local timezone and not receive this warning anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tzlocal.get_localzone`already returns a timezone object, which you can use directly:

```py
import pandas as pd
from tzlocal import get_localzone

z = get_localzone()

print(repr(z))
# _PytzShimTimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'), 'Europe/Berlin')

print(pd.Timestamp("now", tz=z))
# 2023-02-14 17:54:32.445179+01:00
```

You can also unwrap it and obtain the string representation in a way that doesn't trigger warnings:

```py
print(repr(z.unwrap_shim()))
# zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin')

print(z.unwrap_shim().key)
# Europe/Berlin
```

...or also like

```py
from tzlocal import get_localzone_name
print(get_localzone_name())
# Europe/Berlin
```

Note that if you use pandas, you neither need the datetime module nor pytz here.